# What's the difference between loginTimeout, connectTimeout and socketTimeout in pgjdbc

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, database-connection, pg-jdbc

In pgjdbc we have:

- `loginTimeout`
- `connectTimeout`
- `socketTimeout`
- `cancelSignalTimeout`

But it isn't clear to me what's the difference (when are they applied) between `loginTimeout`, `connectTimeout` and `socketTimeout`.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters)? If so what is unclear about that?

Comment: Yes I have. I can't see how `connectTimeout` is different from `loginTimeout`, as far as I understand, the client will establish a SSL connection with the server and then login at the database... So does the `loginTimeout` starts after the SSL connection is established, or does it start together with the `connectTimeout`, since I submitted a login command that happens to use SSL? And will `socketTimeout` be applied at login time as well, since it's a socket read I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the [PostgreSQL JDBC documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters):

> - **loginTimeout** = int
>
>   Specify how long to wait for establishment of a database connection.
>     The timeout is specified in seconds.
> - **connectTimeout** = int
>
>   The timeout value used for socket connect operations. If connecting
>     to the server takes longer than this value, the connection is broken.
>     The timeout is specified in seconds and a value of zero means that it
>     is disabled.
> - **socketTimeout** = int
>
>   The timeout value used for socket read operations. If reading from
>     the server takes longer than this value, the connection is closed.
>     This can be used as both a brute force global query timeout and a
>     method of detecting network problems. The timeout is specified in
>     seconds and a value of zero means that it is disabled.
> - **cancelSignalTimeout** = int
>
>   Cancel command is sent out of band over its own connection, so
>     cancel message can itself get stuck. This property controls "connect
>     timeout" and "socket timeout" used for cancel commands. The timeout is
>     specified in seconds. Default value is 10 seconds.

The `connectTimeout` and `socketTimeout` are timeouts on low-level socket operations. The `connectTimeout` governs the time needed to establish a TCP socket connection. Establishing a TCP connection doesn't guarantee a login (it doesn't even guarantee that you're connecting to a PostgreSQL server, just that you connected to something that accepted your TCP connection). A `socketTimeout` governs the time a socket can be blocked waiting to read from a socket. This involves **all** reads from the server, not just during connect, but also during subsequent interaction with the server (eg executing queries).

On the other hand `loginTimeout` governs the PostgreSQL protocol operation of connecting and authenticating to the PostgreSQL server. This involves establishing a TCP connection followed by one or more exchanges of packets for the handshake and authentication to the PostgreSQL server (I'm not familiar with the details of the PostgreSQL protocol, so I can't be very specific).

Exchanging these packets can take additional time, or if you connected to something that isn't a PostgreSQL server the packet exchange may stall. It might be possible to solve this with careful control of both `connectTimeout` and `socketTimeout`, but there are no guarantees (eg data is being exchanged, but the login never completes). In addition, as the `socketTimeout` also governs all other operations on the connection, you may want to set it higher (eg for other operations that take a long time to get a response back) than you are willing to wait for the login to complete.

The `cancelSignalTimeout` is used as the connect **and** socket timeout of the separate TCP connection used for cancel commands.

Comment: So in a sense `loginTimeout` >= `connectTimeout` >= `socketTimeout`, right?

Comment: @mFeinstein The first two: yes, the last one should be viewed as independent. It could be larger or smaller depending on the effect you want as it is applied to **all** reads from the socket. I'd say you usually want it larger though. If it is smaller than the `loginTimeout`, it is possible that a login is cut short by a read timeout before the login timeout expires (although that will depend on the exact protocol exchange necessary for the login).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 3):

After reading the source, I'd say it is like this:

- `connectTimeout` specifies how long to wait for a TCP network connection to get established
- `loginTimeout` specifies how long the whole process of logging into the database is allowed to take
- `socketTimeout` specifies how long the client will wait for a response to a command from the server before throwing an error

The first two are related to establishing a connection, the third is relevant for the whole database session.

Establishing a TCP connection is *part of* establishing a database connection.